Error : While posting review on Facebook page
I'm getting an error while posting a review on Facebook page using a "POST" method.
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '311823882006106' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "Ar6_ieLkr0wegRXZ4uQtkoG"
}
}
But it was working good when I'm getting a review from Facebook page by using "GET" method
I just want to Post a reviews

Just because they let you read a certain type of object via API, doesn't necessarily mean they let you create that type via API as well. There is no way to publish reviews via API.
